# How to mysql datetime type using index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I Made the table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE rank (
    email  VARCHAR(128),
    hit      INT, 
    date     DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);
CREATE INDEX rank_n1 ON rank (date);
```

And, following questions have been discussed.

```
SELECT email, hit
FROM rank
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-28 23:59:59'
```

But this is a fullscan. How do I use the index?

Comment: Without seeing your dataset it is hard to know - but if that query returns a significant proportion of all rows in the table then you may find that the optimiser believes a fullscan is more efficient than a query scan.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: FORCE INDEX: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Optimizer hints are also available. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos Dammit, they're finally fixing MySQL! I'll remove my comment, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mysql doc (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) Something like this should work:

```
SELECT email, hit
  FROM rank USE INDEX (rank_n1)
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-28 23:59:59'
```